# Why does Facebook API prompt for App Review and doesn't accept Standard Permissions for pages I manage?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This is how my login button looks like:

```
<div
        class="fb-login-button"
        data-width=""
        data-size="large"
        data-button-type="continue_with"
        data-layout="rounded"
        data-scope="pages_show_list"
        data-onlogin="fbAuthCb"
        data-auto-logout-link="true"
        data-use-continue-as="true">
</div>
```

This is my flow:

- Fb.auth (after login) returns a short-lived token that then I exchanged for a 60-day long-lived one.
- At that point I try to query Facebook graph for a page token that then I would use to query the Pages API.

> fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${FB_PAGE_ID}?fields=access_token&access_token=${data.access_token}`)

However, the login dialog, after selecting the page for which I have **editor** role (and **admin** in the app on my account), shows the permission `pages_show_list` requires App View. In theory, I would be able to access such information since I have a role on the page?

Facebook talks about needed the ANALYZE task, but I am not sure what that means. Perhaps I need **another role** to access information such as **analytics and page info**?

Other permissions such as `pages_read_engagement` don't block sign in, but give **auth denied when I call for the page token**.

Comment: The requirement for app review is not based on what role you have on the page, but whether the user has a role in the app.

Comment: Is it different if I sign with my own facebook user, which is also the one who has a role in the page? and if you mean something else (role vs app), **how to add it to the app**?

Comment: You need a role in the app, to be able to grant any permissions that require review, but have not been approved yet. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles

Comment: does the app need to created by the admin of the page, or with a role on the page I can create my own app (on my account) and assign myself? / need to install such app on the page perhaps?

Comment: No, the app does not have to be created by a page admin. What happens now, do you get _asked_ for the permission when you login?

Comment: @CBroe I am admin in my own's fb developer app (no app review or verification done for dev)